# What is causing the following template error 'Invalid block tag: 'blocktrans', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'?

Tags: django, django-templates

What is causing the following template error?

```
In template /var/www/userreg/tagging/templates/registration/login.html, error at line 153

Invalid block tag: 'blocktrans', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'
   143 : 
   144 : 
   145 :    <td>
   146 : 
   147 :    </td>
   148 : </tr>
   149 : </table>
   150 : </td>
   151 :    <td style="text-align:center;">
   152 :        {% if socialaccount.providers  %}
   153 : <p> {% blocktrans with site.name as site_name %} Please sign in with your
 existing acounts through  {% endblocktrans %}
   154 : 
   155 : <div class="socialaccount_ballot">
   156 : 
   157 :   <ul class="socialaccount_providers">
   158 :     {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" %}
   159 :   </ul>
   160 : 
   161 :   <div class="login-or">{% trans 'or' %}</div>
   162 :
   163 : </div>
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: Invalid block tag: 'blocktrans', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'
```

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Installed Applications:

```
 ('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin')
```

Installed Middleware:

```
 ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
```

My template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}   
{% load account %}   
{% load url from future %}

{% block title %}Log in{% endblock %}

{% block content_header %}Log in{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}    
    {% if socialaccount.providers  %}    
    <p> 
       {% blocktrans with site.name as site_name %}
       Please sign in with your existing acounts through     
       {% endblocktrans %}

       <div class="socialaccount_ballot"> 
          <ul class="socialaccount_providers">
          {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" %}    
          </ul>

          <div class="login-or">{% trans 'or' %}</div>  
       </div>

       {% include "socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html" %}

       {% blocktrans %}    
       <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a> for a {{site_name}} account and sign in below:
       {% endblocktrans %}
    </p>   
    {% endif %}         
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Post the markup (template), and the exception... thats all we need.

Comment: It seems that the if that you have in line 152 it's not closed (based on what I could seen). Perhaps you should try adding {% endif %} at the end

Comment: Next time please format your question yourself. I am also wondering whether this is not too localized.

Comment: Do you have `{% load i18n %}` in your template?

Comment: S i have given {%endif%}, still it gives error

Comment: I think the error is inside the included `login_extra.html`

Answer (score 2):

You defined `site_name` at:

```
{% blocktrans with site.name as site_name %}
    Please sign in with your existing acounts 
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Where you didn't referenced it.

But you referenced `site_name` at:

```
{% blocktrans %}
    <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a> for a {{site_name}} account and sign in below:
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Where you didn't declare and define `site_name` at opening `blocktrans` tag.

As I can see from your traceback, django didn't complained, So error may issued from `socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html` or `socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html`.

Answer (score -2):

just `{% endblock %}`, not `{% endblocktrans %}`

Comment: If i gave {% endblock %} alone it is giving some more error like following: TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/

'blocktrans' doesn't allow other block tags (seen u'endblock') inside it

Comment: you are right, my mistake. check the previous answer. he wants to say that you can't use site_name after you have closed the first blocktrans. you have to define it again like that, when you use it.try putting everything in one blocktrans instead of two.